# OpenLdap with Jxplorer: unable to list dc=maxcrc,dc=com

Tags: openldap

i am a newbie to ldap and i am facing an issue while accessing openldap server with jxplorer. I am running openldap on my laptop with windows 7 OS. I have configured the openldap with the BDB database. When i try accessing the ldap server from jxplorer, i get an error that says

```
unable to list dc=maxcrc,dc=com.
unable to perform read entry operation.
```

In the slapd.conf file, the below entries are present.

```
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
```

And also when i try adding entries in the ldap, it fails saying,

"Unable to perform modify operation".

I went through the openldap readme PDF file, but of no help.
Any suggestions
Quick help would be greatly appreaciated :) Thanks in advance

Below is the error details which i saw:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'dc=maxcrc,dc=com'.
```

Comment: You will need to get the extra details out of the error dialog and edit them into your question.

Comment: edited. Can someone please help me through..

Comment: You haven't created the database. You need to run slaptest and slapindex as shown in the documentation. Off topic for SO.

Comment: Is there any links that provides step by step details for this procedure, because i am a newbie to ldap and havent done the setup and configuration before

Comment: The OpenLDAP documentation is all you need.